# Using GIFs with XNA

Tags: c#, xna, gif

I was looking for a way to use GIFs within XNA when I found this: http://xnagif.codeplex.com/

Can anyone tell me the proper steps in adding and linking this library to my project?  I couldn't get it to work when I tried it, and I feel as though I might deleted/overwrite a necessary component to my project.

Comment: Why do you need to use gifs? Animating with spritesheets in XNA is so much easier than using gifs

Comment: Well primarily because my friend had made GIFs beforehand, not knowing they weren't compatible with XNA.  Is it easier though?  I was looking at a tutorial and it looked tedious.

Comment: GIF, JPEG, and BMP have no place in games. For each format, another can do all the same things better: PNG is compressed and lossless (replacing JPEG and BMP), DDS is highly compressed but lossy (replacing JPEG), PNG spritesheets are easier to work with and use than GIF (you could even use APNG), with better features, support, and similar/better compression. All the initial formats are fat and ugly, and GIF and JPEG are both extremely lossy (visibly so in-game). Breaking a GIF down into a spritesheet isn't even hard, you just copy each frame out.

Comment: Agreed. I always work with Pngs and I never had any problem, graphics wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said, spritesheet animation is much easier with spritesheet than gifs and gives you much more flexibility, like storing multiple animations in the same image file.

This nice [tutorial](http://www.berecursive.com/2008/c/sprite-sheets-in-xna-the-basics) will help you get started on spritesheet animation in XNA. It shouldn't take long for you to develop a working animation library with this.

In short, XNA already has a parameter in its Draw method that allows you to draw only a small part of the full image (parameter: source). Using this, you can change the source every X second to make it look like an animated gif. I assure you that it really isn't too complicated and shouldn't be too long to implement (as I have done it myself several times already, always improving my animation engine)

Comment: Plus, if it's your friend who has created the images, I guess he can convert his gif into a spritesheet without too much trouble. This [tool](http://spritesheetpacker.codeplex.com/) also helps to create spritesheets out of separated images easily